# ASP.NET SQL Server session with load balancing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have done something, but I don't know what I need to do next.

I deploy the same site in server A and B, which has the same domain (`http://dev.**.com`).

They have the same `machinekey`, which I declared in the `web.config` in the site.

The session state has pointed to the same `ASPState` database.

As you can see from the following screenshot, the two sites has respective `appId` and `AppName`. That means the two sites cannot share session.

Could anybody tell me what I need to do next? any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Do I need to declare the application name? But where I should to declare it?

Comment: add it again. should i make the appName the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx?msg=2678923).

Comment: hi Darin, my eye must have some problem. it works in my solution.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose an even simpler solution, though I guess I'm a little late to dinner. :)

The IIS 7 Metabase Path of course is the AppName you're seeing, and the AppId is hashed from it. If two IISes are intended to share session, and their AppNames (Metabase Paths) are different, you won't be able to share sessions. There are a bunch of recommendations out there to modify the stored procedure that generates the name, but this seems like a terrible hack to me. While I like the Code Project's solution of keeping out of the stored procedures, there's an even easier way!

Go into IIS 7 Manager on each web server. Select the Web Site you want to share state across IISes. Click *Advanced Settings* off to the right. **Enter a unique value for *ID*, and use the same value on each IIS.** Restart each Web Site and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Change your [TempGetAppID] stored procedure.

example
 SET @appName = LOWER(@appName) 
 -> SET @appName = LOWER(APP_NAME())

APP_NAME() return connectioned application name.
"Application Name=YourAppName;" set to connectionString value.

Hope this help!